# How can I push certain files to origin/master in Git?

Tags: git, push

I am little bit new to Git. I would like to push some files to my Git origin (remote).

What I did:

I had my master, and I created a branch to do some job. After that I merged my branch to my master. During my work, a lot of binary files and project files were changed/added locally. I would like *only* to add *.java* files which changed to remote server.

(I believe that I experimented with *commits* when I worked on my branch, just to check how it work.)

My master is *up to date* with my origin (that is what I get when I do `git pull`. Also I did `git fetch  origin`.
I always received (when I ran `git status`):

```
On branch master Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 12 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean`
```

I tried to *add, commit* those files, but running `git status` wasn't changed. I tried to do *add, commit* on the new branch:

```
On branch NewBranch nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I tried to reset Head. I didn't find a solution for my problem in the Git tutorial or on Stack Overflow.

Of course I can push all files to remote origin, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Some duplicate questions that I found:
[How to push a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479763/how-to-push-a-single-file-in-a-subdirectory-to-github-not-master), [how to push changes made to only certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937405/git-how-to-push-changes-made-to-only-certain-files), and [How to commit only some files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239333/how-to-commit-only-some-files).

Comment: As the first duplicate you linked to says, you can't push just certain files. What you're pushing are commits, which you can think of as snapshots of your files at a point in time. Without doing some special operations (which you should avoid), you'll have to push all or nothing.

Comment: What are the binary files that you don't want to commit? The compiled bins? They should be [`.gitignored`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: not only binary some project files which I changed and I don't want to push.(I add all of them to .gitignore but when I run git diff --stat origin/master I see all of them) so I believe I will also push all of them.

Comment: You have to `git rm` them from the repository then ignore them.

Comment: When I used git for windows I could choose which files to push before synchronize so I thought there must be a simple way. Just curious if people commit the whole project to git so how to they work all together? (if everyone change project files every push)

Comment: I thought about git rm but I can not run git status after it... which can be very annoying to understand what going on....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem: (I was confused with git status response because it wasn't changed when I tried to add/commit files which were already there).Thanks to linuxdan and DaveZych and Temich.

```
git checkout -b NewBranch
```

After that I deleted all unnecessary files.

```
git rm --cache build/web/WEB-INF/classes/doggizz/utils/\*.class
```

Move back to master

```
git checkout master
```

(only disadvantage that those files were deleted when I moved back to master so I copied manually project file , I tried to stash before *checkout* but it didn't helped)

```
git merge NewBranch
git push
```

Answer (score 19):

1. Create a new branch from master
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git checkout -b new_branch`
4. Checkout just the file you want from your old branch
5. `git checkout old_branch path/to/some/file`
6. repeat as necessary for additional files
7. Commit the files to your new branch
8. `git commit -a`
9. Push new branch to origin master branch
10. `git push origin new_branch:master`

Comment: Tnx linuxdan after step 3. git status will return :On branch NewBranch
nothing to commit, working directory clean. so if I push i push everything

Comment: What does your status look like after step 2?

Comment: Shouldn't the last step be `git push origin new_branch:master`? The way it currently is, it's just pushing the local master branch to the remote.

Comment: This is the correct answer because the other files are not deleted.

Comment: It would be interesting if that can be done in a single script? Does anyone have tried it?